# Identity function for CompletableFuture with mutation

Tags: java, completable-future

I'm using `CompletableFuture`s to handle my REST calls.
I have a case where I have to make two calls: one that gives a result, which I will use multiple times; and another which modifies a database with the previous result.

Now, I fixed it like this:

```
final CompletableFuture<A> future1 = f(request);
final CompletableFuture<A> future2 = future1.thenCompose(xml -> {
    g(xml);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(xml);
});
return future2;
```

But is there a way so that I can write it more succinctly, like this:

```
final CompletableFuture<A> future1 = f(request);
final CompletableFuture<A> future2 = future1.thenDoMagic(xml ->
    g(xml)
);
return future2;
```

so that it'll automatically return the value of `future1`, i.e., `xml`?

Comment: Is `g` a blocking call or does it also return a Future?

Comment: `g` also returns a future.

Comment: Then you `compose` over `g` as well, otherwise it does not wait for completion. If you don't need to wait, you might just as well return `future1` directly.

Comment: Either you mean that I just use `combine` directly, which doesn't work because I need to pass `xml` to `g`. Or you mean that I should just return the result of `g(xml)` and then `combine` `future1` and `future2`, which will return `future1`. The way is what I refactored from. I find that approach more tedious. If you suggest another approach, please, elaborate or write some code.

Comment: It is almost what you refactored from, but not quite. Your original version does NOT compose over `g(xml)`, it just kicks off `g`, but ignores the returned future. It does not wait for `g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `g` also returns a future

Then your current code should most likely be adjusted to wait for the completion of that future. As it stands, you are just kicking off `g`, which will run in the background, but your `future2` completes immediately, even before `g` is done.

How about

```
var getXml = f(request); 
return getXml
    // wait for g to complete, but then return xml
    .thenCompose(g)
    .thenCompose(_ -> getXml);
```

If you need this to be more concise, you could make a helper method (say `andThen`) that takes a `Future<X>` and a lambda `X -> Future<?>`, waiting for the second future to complete (purely for side-effects, ignoring the result) but then returning the result of the first.

```
var getXml = f(request);
return andThen(getXml, g);
```

I think there is no built-in for that.